# How to ask about adjustment to something new

Tags: phrase-request

How can we ask to people who moved to new neigherborhood/city/country or who started working a new job at a company or who started going new school if they feel comfort with it/ if they managed to adjust themselves in this new culture. How can we ask that in casual way?

Comment: Thanks for answers.Do  "Were you able to adjust yourself to your new job" and "How are you getting on at new school/job" sound natural?

Comment: To my AmEnglish ear, "Were you able to adjust yourself" implies that there was something wrong or difficult about the process. "settling in" or "getting on" doesn't have that connotation for me.

Comment: "getting on" sounds distincly like BrE (to my AmE ear.)

Comment: You can also use the word "acclimate", example: "Have you gotten acclimated yet?"

Answer (score 4):

I believe the phrase that you're looking for, Murat, is "How are you settling in?"

[Here's a link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/settle%20in?s=t) to the phrase "settle in" at Dictionary.com so you can further explore the topic, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of idiomatic phrases for this. I would say:

> How are you **getting along with** your new job/school?
>   How is your new job/school **working out**?